# Regex to match a JSON String

Tags: javascript, json, regex, unicode

I am building a JSON validator from scratch, but I am quite stuck with the string part. My hope was building a regex which would match the following sequence found on JSON.org:

[image: JSON.org String Sequence]

My regex so far is:

```
/^\"((?=\\)\\(\"|\/|\\|b|f|n|r|t|u[0-9a-f]{4}))*\"$/
```

It does match the criteria with a backslash following by a character and an empty string. But I'm not sure how to use the UNICODE part.

Is there a regex to match any UNICODE character expert " or \ or control character? And will it match a newline or horizontal tab?

The last question is because the regex match the string "\t", but not "    " (four spaces, but the idea is to be a tab). Otherwise I will need to expand the regex with it, which is not a problem, but my guess is the horizontal tab is a UNICODE character.

Thanks to Jaeger Kor, I now have the following regex:

```
/^\"((?=\\)\\(\"|\/|\\|b|f|n|r|t|u[0-9a-f]{4})|[^\\"]*)*\"$/
```

It appears to be correct, but is there any way to check for control characters or is this unneeded as they appear on the non-printable characters on regular-expressions.info? The input to validate is always text from a textarea.

Update: the regex is as following in case anyone needs it:

```
/^("(((?=\\)\\(["\\\/bfnrt]|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}))|[^"\\\0-\x1F\x7F]+)*")$/
```

Comment: The above regular expression suffers from inefficiency and ambiguity which can lead to  malicious user performing a Denial of Service ("DoS") attack. Here is version that is free of the inefficiency:


`/^("(((?=\\)\\(["\\\/bfnrt]|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}))|[^"\\\x00-\x1F\x7F])*")$/`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For your exact question create a character class

```
# Matches any character that isn't a \ or "
/[^\\"]/
```

And then you can just add * on the end to get 0 or unlimited number of them or alternatively 1 or an unlimited number with +

```
/[^\\"]*/
```

or

```
/[^\\"]+/
```

Also there is this below, found at https://regex101.com/ under the library tab when searching for json

```
/(?(DEFINE)
# Note that everything is atomic, JSON does not need backtracking if it's valid
# and this prevents catastrophic backtracking
(?<json>(?>\s*(?&object)\s*|\s*(?&array)\s*))
(?<object>(?>\{\s*(?>(?&pair)(?>\s*,\s*(?&pair))*)?\s*\}))
(?<pair>(?>(?&STRING)\s*:\s*(?&value)))
(?<array>(?>\[\s*(?>(?&value)(?>\s*,\s*(?&value))*)?\s*\]))
(?<value>(?>true|false|null|(?&STRING)|(?&NUMBER)|(?&object)|(?&array)))
(?<STRING>(?>"(?>\\(?>["\\\/bfnrt]|u[a-fA-F0-9]{4})|[^"\\\0-\x1F\x7F]+)*"))
(?<NUMBER>(?>-?(?>0|[1-9][0-9]*)(?>\.[0-9]+)?(?>[eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?))
)
\A(?&json)\z/x
```

This should match any valid json, you can also test it at the website above

EDIT:

[Link to the regex](https://regex101.com/library/tA9pM8)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I added it to my first regular expression and it seems to be working fine. I don't know anything about the control characters, but maybe I don't need to worry about it as the input is from a textarea where they might not be accepted in.

The last regex you provided was a complete regex, but I want to know where the error is. But than again, I'll check it if it might be more useful!

Comment: I have been playing with your latest regex, and when splitting them, they work great! Thanks!

Comment: Thx ! The search url is: https://regex101.com/library?orderBy=MOST_POINTS&search=json

Comment: if you could post a code snippet that uses this regex it would be helpful, I got a lot of syntax errors when I pasted that into my code

Answer (score 4):

Use this, works also with array jsons [{...},{...}]:

```
((\[[^\}]{3,})?\{s*[^\}\{]{3,}?:.*\}([^\{]+\])?)
```

**Demo:**
https://regex101.com/r/aHAnJL/1