# Convert JSON String(Prettified) back to raw string(with all the escape characters)

Tags: javascript, json

So I have a json string as shown below:

```
 {"count":1,"items":[{"rating":"teens","videos":[{"width":1280,"link":"http://192.168.195.86:1081/playback/play/99e2399e-368b","dar_image":1.7777777778,"language":"eng","duration":5166,"type":"main","id":"99e2399e-368b","dar_frame":1.7777777778,"height":720}],"trial":false,"metadata_language":"eng","year":2003,"images":[{"link":"http://192.168.195.86:1081/image/1675610d-e57e.jpg","type":"poster","id":"1675610d-e57e","orientation":"landscape"}],"id":"d0e9d382-e2d4","has_download_policy":true,"title":"Ice Bound","section":"hollywood","crew":[{"role":"director","name":"Roger Spottiswoode"}],"type":"movie","website_url":"http://192.168.195.86:1081/eng/movie/pkdaci6s-ice-bound","description":"Testin'g «ταБЬℓσ»: 1<{2 & 4+1}>3, now 20% off!@#$%^&*(). Another Testing String ","link":"http://192.168.195.86:1081/movie/d0e9d382-e2d4","slug":"pkdaci6s","categories":[{"link":"http://192.168.195.86:1081/category/ca8a9dce-514d","id":"ca8a9dce-514d","title":"Drama"}],"metadata_direction":"ltr","audio_languages":["eng"],"cast":[{"name":"Susan Sarandon"},{"name":"Aidan Devine"},{"name":"Cynthia Mace"}]}],"remaining":1}
```

I need to convert this to a raw string format, where all the special characters and symbols get replaced with unicode or have escape characters.

```
 {"count":1,"items":[{"rating":"teens","videos":[{"width":1280,"link":"http:\/\/192.168.195.86:1081\/playback\/play\/99e2399e-368b","dar_image":1.7777777778,"language":"eng","duration":5166,"type":"main","id":"99e2399e-368b","dar_frame":1.7777777778,"height":720}],"trial":false,"metadata_language":"eng","year":2003,"images":[{"link":"http:\/\/192.168.195.86:1081\/image\/1675610d-e57e.jpg","type":"poster","id":"1675610d-e57e","orientation":"landscape"}],"id":"d0e9d382-e2d4","has_download_policy":true,"title":"Ice Bound","section":"hollywood","crew":[{"role":"director","name":"Roger Spottiswoode"}],"type":"movie","website_url":"http:\/\/192.168.195.86:1081\/eng\/movie\/pkdaci6s-ice-bound","description":"Testin\'g \u2xxx \u2xxx\u2xxx\u2xxx\u2xxx\u2xxx\u2xxx\u2xxx: 1<{2 & 4+1}>3, now 20% off!@#$%^&*(). Another Testing String ","link":"http:\/\/192.168.195.86:1081\/movie\/d0e9d382-e2d4","slug":"pkdaci6s","categories":[{"link":"http:\/\/192.168.195.86:1081\/category\/ca8a9dce-514d","id":"ca8a9dce-514d","title":"Drama"}],"metadata_direction":"ltr","audio_languages":["eng"],"cast":[{"name":"Susan Sarandon"},{"name":"Aidan Devine"},{"name":"Cynthia Mace"}]}],"remaining":1}
```

How will I do this in javascript?
All pointers are welcome.

---

Example link 
http://api.icflix.com/tv/catalogue/movies?num=1

Comment: @xkcd149 , I think that he wants to convert string to string.

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32155133 also "escape" might be a more appropriate term...?

Comment: Your example seems to show you are "escaping" [SLASH] with [BACKSLASH][SLASH].  Why would you do that?  [SLASH] is a "plain-old character" in all languages I'm familiar with, not in need of escaping.

Comment: The server responds with such a form of response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function escapeString(str) {
    var result = '',
        code;

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        code = str.charCodeAt(i);
        if (code < 32 || code > 126) {
            result += '\\u2' + code;
        } else {
            result += str[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}

var orig = '{"count":1,"items":[{"rating":"teens","videos":[{"width":1280,"link":"http://192.168.195.86:1081/playback/play/99e2399e-368b","dar_image":1.7777777778,"language":"eng","duration":5166,"type":"main","id":"99e2399e-368b","dar_frame":1.7777777778,"height":720}],"trial":false,"metadata_language":"eng","year":2003,"images":[{"link":"http://192.168.195.86:1081/image/1675610d-e57e.jpg","type":"poster","id":"1675610d-e57e","orientation":"landscape"}],"id":"d0e9d382-e2d4","has_download_policy":true,"title":"Ice Bound","section":"hollywood","crew":[{"role":"director","name":"Roger Spottiswoode"}],"type":"movie","website_url":"http://192.168.195.86:1081/eng/movie/pkdaci6s-ice-bound","description":"Testin\'g «ταБЬℓσ»: 1<{2 & 4+1}>3, now 20% off!@#$%^&*(). Another Testing String ","link":"http://192.168.195.86:1081/movie/d0e9d382-e2d4","slug":"pkdaci6s","categories":[{"link":"http://192.168.195.86:1081/category/ca8a9dce-514d","id":"ca8a9dce-514d","title":"Drama"}],"metadata_direction":"ltr","audio_languages":["eng"],"cast":[{"name":"Susan Sarandon"},{"name":"Aidan Devine"},{"name":"Cynthia Mace"}]}],"remaining":1} ';

result = escapeString(orig);
console.log(result);
```

Result:

```
{"count":1,"items":[{"rating":"teens","videos":[{"width":1280,"link":"http://192.168.195.86:1081/playback/play/99e2399e-368b","dar_image":1.7777777778,"language":"eng","duration":5166,"type":"main","id":"99e2399e-368b","dar_frame":1.7777777778,"height":720}],"trial":false,"metadata_language":"eng","year":2003,"images":[{"link":"http://192.168.195.86:1081/image/1675610d-e57e.jpg","type":"poster","id":"1675610d-e57e","orientation":"landscape"}],"id":"d0e9d382-e2d4","has_download_policy":true,"title":"Ice Bound","section":"hollywood","crew":[{"role":"director","name":"Roger Spottiswoode"}],"type":"movie","website_url":"http://192.168.195.86:1081/eng/movie/pkdaci6s-ice-bound","description":"Testin'g \u2171\u2964\u2945\u21041\u21068\u28467\u2963\u2187: 1<{2 & 4+1}>3, now 20% off!@#$%^&*(). Another Testing String ","link":"http://192.168.195.86:1081/movie/d0e9d382-e2d4","slug":"pkdaci6s","categories":[{"link":"http://192.168.195.86:1081/category/ca8a9dce-514d","id":"ca8a9dce-514d","title":"Drama"}],"metadata_direction":"ltr","audio_languages":["eng"],"cast":[{"name":"Susan Sarandon"},{"name":"Aidan Devine"},{"name":"Cynthia Mace"}]}],"remaining":1}
```

Or this:

```
result = orig.split('').map(function(v) {
    var code = v.charCodeAt(0);
    if (code < 32 || code > 126) {
        return '\\u2' + code;
    } else {
        return v;
    }
}).join('');

console.log(result);
```

Same result:

```
{"count":1,"items":[{"rating":"teens","videos":[{"width":1280,"link":"http://192.168.195.86:1081/playback/play/99e2399e-368b","dar_image":1.7777777778,"language":"eng","duration":5166,"type":"main","id":"99e2399e-368b","dar_frame":1.7777777778,"height":720}],"trial":false,"metadata_language":"eng","year":2003,"images":[{"link":"http://192.168.195.86:1081/image/1675610d-e57e.jpg","type":"poster","id":"1675610d-e57e","orientation":"landscape"}],"id":"d0e9d382-e2d4","has_download_policy":true,"title":"Ice Bound","section":"hollywood","crew":[{"role":"director","name":"Roger Spottiswoode"}],"type":"movie","website_url":"http://192.168.195.86:1081/eng/movie/pkdaci6s-ice-bound","description":"Testin'g \u2171\u2964\u2945\u21041\u21068\u28467\u2963\u2187: 1<{2 & 4+1}>3, now 20% off!@#$%^&*(). Another Testing String ","link":"http://192.168.195.86:1081/movie/d0e9d382-e2d4","slug":"pkdaci6s","categories":[{"link":"http://192.168.195.86:1081/category/ca8a9dce-514d","id":"ca8a9dce-514d","title":"Drama"}],"metadata_direction":"ltr","audio_languages":["eng"],"cast":[{"name":"Susan Sarandon"},{"name":"Aidan Devine"},{"name":"Cynthia Mace"}]}],"remaining":1}
```

The code considers anything below 32 and above 126 to be special characters.  You need to update it for you scenario.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523514/find-by-key-deep-in-nested-json-object).

You can parse your string using `JSON.parse()` (if you don't already have it as an object), and then recursively run through all its properties. For properties that are neither an object nor an array, encode each value using `encodeURIComponent()`.

**DEMO:**

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8oukjx87/3/).

**CODE:**

Consider `obj` a parsed object from your first JSON string in your question.  Here's the code in case the JSFiddle link breaks:

```
escapeObject(obj);
var escaped = JSON.stringify(obj);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = escaped;

function escapeObject(theObject) {
  var result = null;
  if(theObject instanceof Array) {
    for(var i = 0; i < theObject.length; i++) {
        result = escapeObject(theObject[i]);
        if (result) {
            break;
        }   
    }
  }
  else
  {        
      for(var prop in theObject) {    
        if (typeof theObject[prop] == typeof "") {
          var escValue = encodeURIComponent(theObject[prop]);
          theObject[prop] = escValue;  
        }
        if(theObject[prop] instanceof Object || theObject[prop] instanceof Array) {
            result = escapeObject(theObject[prop]);
            if (result) {
                break;
            }
        }

    };
  }
  return result;
}
```