# Regex to match a JSON encoded String

Tags: java, json, string

Hi I've been trying to create a Regex in Java to match JSON data that I have converted to a string using json_encode. I've been reading through examples on stackoverflow but I'm not sure do they just relate to pure JSON or strings containing JSON representation. I've tried applying a few but can't get them to work.

Looking here:

[Regex to validate JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583472/regex-to-validate-json)

And here:

[Regex to match a JSON String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32155133/regex-to-match-a-json-string)

This is the string I am trying to use my Regex to match to:

```
[{"resourceUri":"file:\/home\/admin\/test-modeling\/apache-tomcat-7.0.70\/temp\/IOS\/filetest-file-files.txt#\/\/@statements.12\/@typeList.0\/@enumLiterals.11","severity":"WARNING","lineNumber":333,"column":9,"offset":7780,"length":24,"message":"Enum name should be less than 20 characters"}]
```

I've tried using this answer and it matches fine when I use regex101 for testing.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6249375/5476612

I'm using this regex from here:

```
/\A("([^"\\]*|\\["\\bfnrt\/]|\\u[0-9a-f]{4})*"|-?(?=[1-9]|0(?!\d))\d+(\.\d+)?([eE][+-]?\d+)?|true|false|null|\[(?:(?1)(?:,(?1))*)?\s*\]|\{(?:\s*"([^"\\]*|\\["\\bfnrt\/]|\\u[0-9a-f]{4})*"\s*:(?1)(?:,\s*"([^"\\]*|\\["\\bfnrt\/]|\\u[0-9a-f]{4})*"\s*:(?1))*)?\s*\})\Z/is
```

However when I try and use it as a string in Java I get escaped character issues.

Can anyone help me with fixing the regex to work as a String to use in Java or help me create one that will work?

**EDIT 1:** Here's the full String I am looking at that I am trying to match the JSON string above against:

```
../../tool/model/toolingValidationReport.php?fileName=test-testing-types.txt&fileSize=18380&validationReport=[{"resourceUri":"file:\/home\/admin\/test-modeling\/apache-tomcat-7.0.70\/temp\/IOS\/filetest-file-files.txt#\/\/@statements.12\/@typeList.0\/@enumLiterals.11","severity":"WARNING","lineNumber":333,"column":9,"offset":7780,"length":24,"message":"Enum name should be less than 20 characters"}] target=
```

**EDIT 2:** Here's the Java I am using to perform the regex check. The `href` variable contains the String content shown in edit 1.

```
Pattern validationReportPattern = Pattern.compile(getValidationReportPattern());
Matcher validationReportMatcher = validationReportPattern.matcher(href);

public String getYangValidationReportPattern(){
   return "(\\[\\{.*\\}])"; 
}

String validationReport  = validationReportMatcher.group(1);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do , are you trying to see if an attribute in the JSON is present ? Trying to parse this into a JSON Object ?  What are you trying to match ?

Comment: I'm unsure what exactly you want to match. For example with `\[{.*}]` you match everything inside `[{` and  `}]`, see in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aKwHhK/1). In java you would have to use: `\\[{.*}]` to escape the backslash.

Comment: Hi Andre, thank you for the answer. I'm trying to match to the json string I listed above, I'll update the question to make that clearer. Your answer again works fine in regex101 but when I try and use it in Java and escape it it's still not matching the string. This is the regex I'm now trying to use in Java: `"(\\[\\{.*\\}])"`

Comment: @olliejjc16 I don't think you want to escape `{` or `}`. To use you regex in Java just escape every `\ ` and `"` from your original regex.

Comment: @kalsowerus I had to use the escapes for them as I would get an illegal repetition error if I didn't

Comment: It works fine for me (with the escaped `{}`). Are you sure your JSON does not contain any leading or trailing whitespace characters?

Comment: Ya I can't figure it out, I've trimmed the string so that should prevent the whitespace characters issue right? Its really annoying because it matches fine on online regex matchers but I keep getting no match found error

Comment: [`trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) just removes leading and trailing whitespaces. Maybe there is whitespace between `[` and `{` or `]` and `}`. Why not just print the string out?

Comment: @AndreKampling hi printed out the entire string I'm searching through like you said its in my main post

Comment: Post the calls in your code where you trying to match...

Comment: @AndreKampling Added in edit 2

Comment: If you copy the regex from regex101 and paste it in IntelliJ / Android studio, it should automagically escape the necessary characters and work.

Comment: Looks like an XY Problem to me. Regex is not a good tool for consuming JSON. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @slim: Generally I would agree when talking about parsing that string. But he just want to extract the Json string. After this he can parse it as you said.

Comment: It's a URL path, so the smart thing to do is to parse it as a URL and take the relevant query parameter. Again, URL libraries are easy to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex pattern must be `"(\\[\\{.*}])"` in Java but the real problem is that no match has been attempted. You have to call [find()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) before calling [group()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int)).

If you do that it works, [see here online at ideone](https://ideone.com/QVx93A).

**Output:**

```
Match: [{"resourceUri":"file:\/home\/admin\/test-modeling\/apache-tomcat-7.0.70\/temp\/IOS\/filetest-file-files.txt#\/\/@statements.12\/@typeList.0\/@enumLiterals.11","severity":"WARNING","lineNumber":333,"column":9,"offset":7780,"length":24,"message":"Enum name should be less than 20 characters"}]
```

The `find()` method returns a boolean so that you can check if there is an occurrence.
If you would not check that with `find()` first you would get an `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found` exception.

```
if (validationReportMatcher.find())
{
   String validationReport  = validationReportMatcher.group(1);
   System.out.println ("Match: " + validationReport);
}
else
{
   System.out.println ("No match");
}
```

If you have to search for multiple matches you call `find()` in a while loop:

```
while (validationReportMatcher.find())
{
   String validationReport  = validationReportMatcher.group(1);
   System.out.println ("Match: " + validationReport);
}
```

But this seems not to be neccessary as you just look for one occurrence.