# Matching and replace multiple strings in python

Tags: python, python-re

```
import re
text = '{"mob":"1154098431","type":"user","allowOrder":false,"prev":1}'

newstring = '"allowOrder":true,"'
#newstring = '"mob":"nonblocked",'

reg = '"allowOrder":(.*?),"|"mob":"(.*?)",'
r = re.compile(reg,re.DOTALL)
result = r.sub(newstring, text)

print (result)
```

**im trying to matching and replacing multiple regex patterns with exact values can someone help me to achieve this**

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to parse the JSON, manipulate it, and dump it back as a string? Why use regexes here?

Comment: i tho this would be easier at least for me

Comment: Okay. What's the intended output? You mention that you want multiple replacements - what should the replaced value be?

Comment: output = {"allowOrder":true,""type":"user","allowOrder":true,"prev":1}   i need to multiple change mob and allowOrder with different values

Comment: This is easy: `import json; data = json.loads(text); data['allowOrder'] = True; data['mob'] = 'nonblocked'; data_dump = json.dumps(data)`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32155765) is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should parse the JSON rather than trying to use regex for this. Luckily that's real straightforward.

```py
import json

text = '{"mob":"1154098431","type":"user","allowOrder":false,"prev":1}'
obj = json.loads(text)  # "loads" means "load string"

if 'allowOrder' in obj:
    obj['allowOrder'] = True
if 'mob' in obj:
    obj['mob'] = 'nonblocked'

result = json.dumps(obj)  # "dumps" means "dump to string"

assert '{"mob": "nonblocked", "type": "user", "allowOrder": true, "prev": 1}' == result
```

Comment: working fine but with spaces between chars  {"mob": "nonblocked", "type": "user", "allowOrder": true, "prev": 1}}

Comment: fixed by result = json.dumps(obj, separators=(',', ':'))